# i can't push anything to git using git lfs although i reduce the size of repository

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-lfs

i'm using git lfs for putting large file in github. today i recieve this email:

> Git LFS has been disabled on your personal account because you’ve exceeded your data plan by at least 150%. Please purchase additional data packs to cover your bandwidth and storage usage:
>
> https://github.com/account/billing/data/upgrade
> i don't want to purchase so i deleted all of my files from github to reduce the size. so now there is no file in github. and now i want to push a small file to github with the following command:

```
 git push origin master
```

but the result is as the following:

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/19), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/something/something.git'
```

why? i deleted all of the files from github and the size should be very small but it doesn't let me to push anything. what should i do?

Comment: Talk with GitHub. You ran over some quota and they've flagged your account; removing items won't reset the flag. Note that this has nothing to do with Git itself.

Comment: @torek But keep in mind that it also might be the case that the OP's history still has some CLOB/BLOB stuff in the history somewhere.  Simply deleting from the current branch and pushing doesn't do anything to the history.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That would be the case except for this `batch response` thing, which happens first (LFS part, before Git gets involved). (Also I suspect their main flag is bandwidth usage at this point, though that's minor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still getting the quota error most likely because you still have commits in one or more branches containing very large files.  Keep in mind that your Git history is a snapshot of everything which has ever happened.  Deleting the files from the current branch and pushing just means you won't add *more* very large content.  The content already in the history would still be there.

To get an idea on how to get started removing the large files from you repo, see this helpful Stack Overflow question:

[How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)